# Passing structs of a linked list by reference

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am working on a final project that requires implementing a linked list for a card game. The dealer's hand and the player's hand both should be linked list as well as the deck of cards.

My problem that I faced was when I tried to create a function that adds the values (cards from the end of the deck list) to it. Passing the list it self and its tail does not update their values. I could make the function so that it returns the head pointer, but then I won't be able to keep note of its tail.

I am really sorry, as this is something new to me and I have never programmed before this course in my life. If some of the logic in my function seems needlessly difficult to read, or straight up doesn't make sense, please pardon me.

I've tried endlessly to try and make this work, but I have a feeling I'm doing something fundamentally wrong

```
typedef struct card_s { 
    char suit[20]; 
    int face; 
    struct card_s *next, *previous; 
} card;

card* createHands(card* head, card *cards) {
    card *tail = NULL, *temp = NULL, *temp1;

    // Go to end of deck
    while (cards->next != NULL) {
        cards = cards->next;
        }

        temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
        strcpy(temp->suit, cards->suit);
        temp->face = cards->face;
        if (head == NULL) { // If the list for the hand doesn't exist, create head
            head = temp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
        }
            tail = temp;
            tail->next = NULL;

        temp1 = cards->previous; 
        free(cards); // to delete the node added from the deck

        cards = temp1;
        cards->next = NULL;
        while (cards->previous != NULL) {
            cards = cards->previous;
        }

    return head;

}
```

Obviously this will just add any value I give it over the previous value. It's not by any mean a connected list.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to *free* the old node, and malloc a new node - just put *that* node into the correct list and be done with it!

Comment: I see what you mean, i'll fix that as soon as I'm able to fix the function.

Comment: N,o you should strive to produce a [mcve] in your question. Notice for example how the last while loop doesn't actually have any effect.

Comment: You're never setting the `previous` for your allocated node. All this stems from the fact that your function is so complicated that **everyone** is having hard time trying to figure what's happening in there.

Comment: `if (head == NULL) ` - when would that *not* be true on initial entry to this function? I mean, when you ever pass a non-null `head` to this thing? What exactly is this function supposed to be doing? If you can't walk your code and [explain it to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), you're going to have a very difficult time trying to explain it to *us*.

Comment: Could you add some comment on what `createHands` is suppose to do ? I have a very hard time inferring from the name of the parameters. My guess is that you want your function to `add` a `card` into a `hand`

Comment: If head != NULL you are dereferencing the null pointer tail and that's an error.

Comment: if I well understand you want to extract a card from the deck to add it in the list of the player/dealer, see my answer

Comment: The function is supposed to extract the last card from the deck and add it to the hand's linked list. As for (head = NULL) this supposes that I'm giving the function a linked list, if it hasn't been created before, initialize the head.. So essentially, I'm passing a linked a list that I want to add what's at the end of the deck to it, and then free that card from the deck

Comment: @Bruno, yes you're absolutely right. That's what I want to do. I will give your code a look and try to implement it. I just have a question, how will I be passing the deck so that I can use ** in the function's parameter?

Comment: "_how will I be passing the deck ..._" @SteveSonOfJobs I do in the _main_ in my answer : `&deck` with `card * deck`, look at the full program at the end of my answer

Comment: @SteveSonOfJobs please, is my answer solved your question ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several obvious problems in your code :

- `while (cards->next != NULL)` supposes *cards* is not NULL
- if *head* is not NULL you do `tail->next = temp;` but *tail* is NULL
- you free the last cell from *cards* without updating that list, so its last element is now freed

---

If I well understand the second argument of *createHands* is the deck and the goal if to extract its last card to add it to the dealer/player list and return the new head of it.

Note you need to get the deck as `card **` to be able to set that list to NULL when you extract the last card. It is also possible to follow the same way for the list of the dealer/player but visibly you prefer to return the new head rather than to have the first parameter to be `card ** head`.

Supposing the card must be added on the head a solution can be :

```
card * createHands(card * head, card ** deck) {
  if (deck == NULL)
    // no available card
    return head;

  // Go to end of deck
  while ((*deck)->next != NULL) {
    deck = &(*deck)->next;
  }

  card * c = *deck; // the extracted card

  *deck = NULL; // remove it from the deck

  c->previous = NULL;

  if (head != NULL) {
    c->next = head;
    head->previous = c;
  }

  return c;
}
```

---

A full program to check :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct card_s { 
    char suit[20]; 
    int face; 
    struct card_s *next, *previous; 
} card;

card * createHands(card * head, card ** deck) {
  if (deck == NULL)
    // no available card
    return NULL;

  // Go to end of deck
  while ((*deck)->next != NULL) {
    deck = &(*deck)->next;
  }

  card * c = *deck; // the extracted card

  *deck = NULL; // remove it from the deck

  c->previous = NULL;

  if (head != NULL) {
    c->next = head;
    head->previous = c;
  }

  return c;
}

// check

card * mk(const char * s, card * n)
{
  card * c = malloc(sizeof(card));

  strcpy(c->suit, s);
  c->next = n;

  if (n != 0)
    n->previous = c;

  return c;
}

void pr(const char * who, card * c)
{
  printf("%s cards :", who);
  while (c != NULL) {
    printf(" %s", c->suit);
    c = c->next;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  card * deck = mk("one", mk("two", mk("three", mk("four", mk("five", NULL)))));
  card * dealer = NULL;
  card * player = NULL;

  pr("deck", deck);

  puts("->dealer");
  dealer = createHands(dealer, &deck);
  pr("deck", deck);
  pr("dealer", dealer);

  puts("->player");
  player = createHands(player, &deck);
  pr("deck", deck);
  pr("player", player);

  puts("->dealer");
  dealer = createHands(dealer, &deck);
  pr("deck", deck);
  pr("dealer", dealer);

  puts("->player");
  player = createHands(player, &deck);
  pr("deck", deck);
  pr("player", player);

  puts("->dealer");
  dealer = createHands(dealer, &deck);
  pr("deck", deck);
  pr("dealer", dealer);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -g l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
deck cards : one two three four five
->dealer
deck cards : one two three four
dealer cards : five
->player
deck cards : one two three
player cards : four
->dealer
deck cards : one two
dealer cards : three five
->player
deck cards : one
player cards : two four
->dealer
deck cards :
dealer cards : one three five
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of assumption of what the function is suppose to do

```
typedef struct card_s { 
    char suit[20]; 
    int face; 
    struct card_s *next, *previous; 
} card;
```

You want to add a card in your hand

```
card* AddCard(card* hand, card* draw) {
    // check input
    if(draw == NULL ) {return NULL;} 

    // create a copy of the card
    card* newCard=malloc(sizeof(card));
    if(newCard == NULL) {return hand;} // check malloc result
    memcpy(newCard, draw, sizeof(card));
    newCard->next=NULL;
    newCard->previous=NULL;

    if(hand==NULL) {return newCard;} // if the hand was null just return the card

    // find where to append the card
    card* tail=hand; 
    while(tail->next != NULL) {tail = tail->next;}
    // append the card to the end of the hand
    tail->next = newCard;
    newCard->previous = tail;
    return hand;
}
```